# Why are the closing body and html tags on my page showing in red in Brackets?

Tags: html, debugging, syntax-error

I downloaded the exercise files for a tutorial on responsive animated websites and in my code editor (Brackets) at the end of the page the body and html tags are showing in red as if there is an error and I have no idea why.  Can anyone tell me?

Also, what's the best way to find out myself?  I clicked on "Debug" in the Brackets toolbar but it just gave me the lines where the errors were - 167 and 168 on the page, nothing more.  Not much help.  Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>The Gym - Personal Training</title>
    <link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />  
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/waypoints.css">
    <script src="js/query.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div id="header-inner">
        <a href="index.html" id="logo"></a>
        <nav>
        <a href="a" id="menu-icon"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>  
                <li><a href="a">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="a">Facility</a></li>
                <li><a href="a">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="a">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    </header>
<!--- Start Slider -->
        <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script><!--For Image Slider-->

    <div class="slide-wrap">
        <section class="slider">
            <ul class="slider1">
                <li><img src="https://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/chest-fly.png"></li>
            <li><img src="https://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/push-ups.png"></li>
            <li><img src="https://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/inside-gym.png"></li>
            <li><img src="https://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/training.png"></li>
            </ul>
    </section>
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.slider1').bxSlider({
                mode: 'fade',
                captions: false,
                auto:true,
                pager:false,

            });
            $('.slider2').bxSlider({
                pager:false,
                captions: true,
                maxSlides: 3,
                minSlides: 1,
                slideWidth: 230,
                slideMargin: 10
            });
            $('.slider3').bxSlider({
                mode: 'fade',
                captions: false,
                auto:true,
                pager:false,
                controls:false,
            });
        </script>
<!--- End Slider -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="inner-wrapper">

        <!---Start Waypoints  Delayd Animation --->
        <section class="staggered-animation-container">

<section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInLeftBig" data-os-animation-delay=".3s">

        <section class="one-third">
            <div class="circle">
                <td><i class="fa fa-users"></i></td>
            </div>
            <h3>Grade A Staff</h3>
            <p>Here at The Gym we have the best trainsing staff in the tri-state area as we seek out and recruit talented trainers with all the right cetifications.  Come in today and have a sit down with one of our trainers so we can help you meet your golas in the fastest way possible!</p>
        </section>
    </section>
<section class="one-third">
            <div class="circle">
                <td><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></td>
            </div>
            <h3>A Convenient Location</h3>
            <p>Here at The Gym we have the best trainsing staff in the tri-state area as we seek out and recruit talented trainers with all the right cetifications.  Come in today and have a sit down with one of our trainers so we can help you meet your golas in the fastest way possible!</p>
        </section>    
<section class="one-third">
            <div class="circle">
                <td><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i></td>
            </div>
            <h3>Check us out - free!</h3>
            <p>Here at The Gym we have the best trainsing staff in the tri-state area as we seek out and recruit talented trainers with all the right cetifications.  Come in today and have a sit down with one of our trainers so we can help you meet your golas in the fastest way possible!</p>
        </section>    
 <div class="clearfix"></div>   
    <article>
        <img src="https://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/gym-classes.png" class="circle-image">
         </article>
        <aside>
        <h3>Our Facility</h3>
            <br>
            <ul class="gym">
                <li><h4>Unlimited wifi Connection</h4></li>
                <li><h4>member music requests &amp; voting</h4></li>
                <li><h4>open 24 hours / 7 days a week</h4></li>
                <li><h4>cardio machine movie theater</h4></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <section class="one-third">
        <h3>Ladies Section</h3>
        <img src="https://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/ladies-gym.jpg">
            <p>Included in our facility is a "ladies only" section of the gym where women can work out by themselves.</p>
        </section>  
        <section class="one-third">
            <h3>the gym floor</h3>
            <img src="https://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/gym-floor.jpg">
            <p>Our gym is as spacious as they come.  Enjoy scenic views from the cardio equipment on the third floor.</p>
        </section>
        <section class="one-third">
            <h3>free weights</h3>
            <img src="https://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/free-weights.jpg">
            <p>Our free weights section has an extensive collection of dumbbels and Olympic plates for body building.</p>
        </section>

        <!---End Inner Wrapper--->
 <div class="clearfix"></div> 
     <footer>
        <div id="footer-inner">
            <section class="one-third" id="footer-third">
            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <p class="footer-contact">The Gym<br>
                <b class="phone">555-555-5555</b><br><br>500 Washington Road<br>Seattle, WA  98101</p></section> 
           <section class="one-third" id="footer-third">
            <h3>Social</h3> 
               <br>
            <ul class="social">
               <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/w3newbie" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li><li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+DrewRyan_3/posts" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://twitter.com/DrewOnCue" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/drewoncue" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
               </ul>   
            </section>
            <section class="one-third" id="footer-third-last">
            <h3>Pages</h3>
            <br>
            <h5>
                <a href="index.html">home</a> <a href="#">about</a> <a href="#">facility</a> <a href="#">pricing</a> 
                <a href="#">contact</a>
            </h5>
            </section>            
            </div>
        </footer>       
    <footer class="second">
        <p>&copy; The Gym, 2017</p></footer>  
        <!---End Waypoints Delayed Animation --->
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue, and apparently, it's because of the unordered list (in my project). It looks like it believes an unordered list cannot be enclosed in P tags. It renders fine in the browser. I guess I'll check to see what the markup rules for that are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try collapsing all the nested tags and see if you're left with any that are not properly closed.

Comment: How does one do this?  By manually clicking each individual arrow next to a tag?  As shown in the screenshot below, when I do this for the div "inner-wrapper", it shows the closing div tag in red (actually I can't paste a screen shot here - don't know why).  Why?  There has to be a closing tag.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how you do it. I am looking at your code on my phone, but it does seem to me that your inner-wrapper div is never closed. where does it show you the ending tag in red? Is it just before the closing tag of the body? Because that's where it should be displayed, I think. If you have no end tag before the ending tag of body, try adding one and see if the error disappears.

Comment: Sorry - another poster had pointed out there was no inner-wrapper closing tag so when I inserted it (before the comment "end inner-wrapper") that's where it showed in red.  But I did as you suggested and I put it before the body tag and now all red tags are gone.  What's weird is that in the video, it shows a closing section tag followed by a closing div tag before the "end inner-wrapper here" comment, which is right before the footer.  Unfortunately, when I view the page in live preview, the 1st "one-thirds" class section does not display (between the "slide-wrap" div and the aside).

Comment: Ok, so from what I can tell, your HTML has a header, inner-wrapper and footer structure. Inside each one of these tags, you have sections. But the thing is, you have a section end tag before the body end tag, without a div end tag. Since you have a comment stating where your inner wrapper should end, try adding the section end tag, followed by the div end tag before that comment and remove the section end tag that's just before the body end tag.

Comment: Whew!  That did it, thanks!  Seems like this situation must come up a lot and with code that's a lot more complex, and there should be some automated tool to run your code through that would tell you this instantly.  Anyway, thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad that helped! For validating HTML code, you could use a code validator like [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org). You'll notice it gives you lots of errors regarding the syntax that is improper, even though those errors do not affect the display of the page. The last error it gives is the one related to inner-wrapper. Hope this helps you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the comments wrong, its: `<!-- COMMENT -->`, not `<!--- --->`